# Netty - Client/Server chat

Tags: java, client-server, netty

I need to have a client/server communication in netty for one of my project purpose. So I just started with a handsOn to improve from that.I am learning netty and I am a beginner in that.

I have tried a simple client server chatting with netty.

The client and server is getting initialized and I could see the server is able to get the Client pipeline for connection establishment, but when the client sends the message, it is not getting inside the messageReceived part of the ServerAdapterHandler. Below are my source codes,

CLIENT:

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;

public class ContainerClient {

    String server;
    int port;
    int containerPort;

    public ContainerClient(String server, int port, int containerPort) {
        this.server = server;
        this.port = port;
        this.containerPort = containerPort;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String server = "localhost";
        int port = 5252;
        int containerPort = 8094;
        new ContainerClient(server, port, containerPort).start();
    }

    public void start() {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap().group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new ClientAdapterInitializer());

            Channel channel = bootstrap.connect(server, port).sync().channel();

            channel.write("Hi\n");
            channel.write("Hi\n");
            channel.write("Hi\n");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT CHANNEL INITIALIZER:

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;

public class ClientAdapterInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());

        pipeline.addLast("handler", new ClientAdapterHandler());
    }

}
```

CLIENT MESSAGE HANDLER:

```
 import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter;

public class ClientAdapterHandler extends
        ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter<String> {

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext context, String message)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println(message);
        if (message.equals("quit"))
            throw new ServerEndedException("Server is closed");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, Object arg1)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext arg0)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void channelWritabilityChanged(ChannelHandlerContext arg0)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

SERVER:

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;

public class ContainerServer {

    int port;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ContainerServer().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        port = 5252;
        EventLoopGroup producer = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup consumer = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {

            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
                    .group(producer, consumer)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ServerAdapterInitializer());
            System.out.println("Server started");
            bootstrap.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            producer.shutdownGracefully();
            consumer.shutdownGracefully();
        }

    }

}
```

SERVER CHANNEL INITIALIZER:

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelPipeline;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;

public class ServerAdapterInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());

        pipeline.addLast("handler", new ServerAdapterHandler());
    }

}
```

SERVER MESSAGE HANDLER:

```
import io.netty.channel.Channel;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup;
import io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup;
import io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor;

public class ServerAdapterHandler extends
        ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter<String> {

    private static final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(
            "containers", GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

    @Override
    public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("[START] New Container has been initialzed");
        channels.add(ctx.channel());
        super.handlerAdded(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void handlerRemoved(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("[END] A Container has been removed");
        channels.remove(ctx.channel());
        super.handlerRemoved(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String arg1)
            throws Exception {
        Channel currentChannel = ctx.channel();
        System.out.println("[INFO] - " + currentChannel.remoteAddress() + " - "
                + arg1);
        currentChannel.write("[Server] - Success");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean beginMessageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Message received");
        return super.beginMessageReceived(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, Object arg1)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("channelRead");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext arg0)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("channelReadComplete");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelWritabilityChanged(ChannelHandlerContext arg0)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("channelWritabilityChanged");
    }

}
```

Below is the output I am getting in server and nothing in client:

```
Server started
[START] New Container has been initialzed
channelReadComplete
[END] A Container has been removed
```

But The expected should be,

```
Server started
[START] New Container has been initialzed
channelReadComplete
[INFO] - localhost - Hi
[INFO] - localhost - Hi
[INFO] - localhost - Hi
[END] A Container has been removed
```

And I should get response in client as,

```
[Server] - Success
[Server] - Success
[Server] - Success
```

I tried with line Delimter in framer also, but same results.

Someone could you please help on this?

Thanks in advance!!.

Comment: please create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version of your code

Comment: My aplogies for that. I tried though, but I am not sure where the error is, thats why I gave all my classes.

Comment: what version of netty are you using? my guess is that you need to flush the channel after writing to it.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. But no use. The thing is, my first message from client itself not reaching the server. Else do you have any better blogs written for io.netty. I am using netty 4.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me with the following change to the `start` method in your `ContainerClient`. Just add a `channel.flush()`.

```
public void start() {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap().group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).handler(new ClientAdapterInitializer());

        Channel channel = bootstrap.connect(server, port).sync().channel();

        channel.write("Hi\n");
        channel.write("Hi\n");
        channel.write("Hi\n");
        channel.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

The `ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter` does not exist anymore in newer version of 4.0. I used a `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`.

```
public class ServerAdapterHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
        Channel currentChannel = ctx.channel();
        System.out.println("[INFO] - " + currentChannel.remoteAddress() + " - " + msg);
        currentChannel.write("[Server] - Success");
    }

}
```

Comment: Also looks like I am shutting down the group as soon as the client sends the message. If I want the server reply I might need a loop or sleep over there to wait for the server to respond

Comment: yep, if you want to keep the channel active you would need to put the `shutdownGracefully()` call in a separate method and call it whenever you want to close the channel.